# How to pass the result of one test case to another test case in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am running multiple test case in robot framework.

I wish to pass the result of one test case to another test case. Is there any way to do the same.

## Example

**TC01-Search and Navigate to Required Vessel**

```
Given Home Page is Loaded
When Search Ship and Choose Required Vessel
${name}   ${no}  Navigate to the Vessel View
```

**TC02-Verify Vessel Details in Case**

`Given Cases is Available in Apps
   And I Navigate to Cases
   Then Verify Vessel Details are present or not   ${name}  ${no}`

Here I have to pass  ${name}  and ${no} from TC-01 to TC-02.
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below keyword

Set Suite Variable  name, *values
Makes a variable available everywhere within the scope of the current suite.

The above keyword can be used to reuse the test data in different test cases